# C# / .NET MVC Razor language translation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

this is the first time that I'm encountering this issue so I wanted to shed some light on this matter. I'm building a .NET MVC application which consumes a JSON web service, and the response messages from that server are written in chinese mandarin language. With each message comes a corresponding status code with it's English translation (not in the reply itself but documentation). So later on I noticed that not all errors are covered in the documentation and that I don't have their  status code thus I don't know what they mean except I translate them through google translate. I figured if I used some kind of translation library that offers this kind of service where I can translate Chinese mandarin into English, it would be really nice.

What would you guys suggest I' should do here?

Every advice is helpful as I want to maintain the code as simple as I can without including any extra library that I don't really need.

Thanks a lot ! =)

P.S. so the respons message example is like following:

```
该运输方式不可用
```

Which would translate to:

```
The shipping method is not available
```

Comment: add the missing codes

Comment: @Seabizkit there might be 5 of them and there might be 5000 of them... It would be literally impossible to do that...

Comment: I dont think it would, just ask for the updated documentation.... ie if there only 15 would it make sense to build an entire translation api.... probably not!

Comment: programs for a process usually would not have more than 20 status codes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you used the google translate api? https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text

Comment: Please do not answer clearly [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. It only invites more such questions in the future.